# How can i add a date field to a text file data for each row using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have 5000 lines of data generated by another program written to a text file,End of each line i need to add a date column insert a current system date for each line.
I also want to add another custom field after the date called vendor which has value of "12345" for all the rows. so i need date and vendor field attached to all those 5000 lines using batch scripting. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @joelgoldstick - he says batch twice.

Comment: can you post a few example lines? Solution depends on syntax and length.

Comment: sorry for the delay.

Comment: here you go... the line starts with "JE Networks" and Ends with a number and i need a date column at the end. can we rearrange the columns  for example i need data column(7870.24) some where in between is that possible                                                                                             "JE Networks" 219360 "4508" "Div1" 1140 "Apr" "Estimate" 7870.24
"JE Networks" 219360 "4508" "Div59" 1140 "Apr" "Estimate" 159.93

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your data is `<TAB>` delimited.

```
@echo off
set "vendor=whatever"
(
    (for /f "tokens=1-8 delims= " %%a in (infile.txt) do (
        REM                    ^- this is a TAB     
        echo %%a    %%b %%c %%d %%f %%g %%h %date%  %vendor%
        REM       ^-   ^- etc.: all these whitespaces are TABs
    )
)>outfile.txt
```

To rearrange the colums, just shuffle the tokens as you need them, for example

```
echo %date% %%a %%d %%b %%g %vendor%    %%f %%h %%c %%e
```

Comment: Thank You Stephan!! i will test this out and give an update.

Comment: i tested this i just changed vendor =219360, infile as c:\test\infile and outfile as c:\test\outfile and ran the script it doesnt do anything. it appears to be simple i think i might get through it hopefully. please let me if i need to change anything.

Comment: Is there anything in `outfile.txt`? Any messages on the screen?

Comment: nothing but when i executed just the statement it gives me this error                                     for /f "tokens=1-8 delims= " %%a in (c:\\test\\infile.txt) do (echo %%a    %%b %%c %%d %%f %%g %%h %date%  %vendor%)                                  %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: `%%a` syntax is intended for use in batchfiles only. On command line just use `%a`, but in this case, this doesn't help, because `%a` is not defined without the `for`.

Comment: C:\test>(for /f "tokens=1-8 delims= " %a in ('c:\test\infile.txt') do echo %date)
>C:\test\Outfile.txt                                                                                                 this command just opens a infile.txt and does nothing to it and doesn`t write anything to Outfile.txt

Comment: remove the single quotes around `c:\test\infile.txt` and it's `%date%`